# Alternatives to libxmljs

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath, node.js

Goal: Use Node.js to access a web page, manipulate the DOM using xpath syntax, and print the new DOM.

libxmljs is okay, but it has several dependencies which NPM doesn't resolve. Which libraries do you use to xpath arbitrary HTML?

Comment: Investigate into libraries like [`zombie`](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) and [`jsdom`](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) instead.

Comment: why you need to build? cant you run inside a browser?

Comment: This isn't an XPath question at all. Use a more appropriate tag, such as xpath-implementations, or whatever you consider most precise.

Comment: @ariel: Node.js is server-side. @Dimitre: This IS an xpath question. I want an xpath selector for arbitrary HTML, libxmljs isn't Mac-compatible, so I'm asking for alternatives.

Comment: I've just npm install libxmljs on osx with macports and the build just went fine

Answer (score 2):

I develop libxmljs on Mac OS X, so this shouldn't be your major hurdle. You need the `libxml2` library and the `scons` utility in order to build successfully. Both of these are available via macports or homebrew. Once you have libxml2, make sure the xml2-config command-line utility is in your path. That's what I use to get the appropriate build flags.

@mcandre I believe you're the same person who submitted a ticket to the github repo. I hope you've gotten things worked out. If not, give more info about your problem. https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs

:Marco

Comment: Yes and no. While libxmljs does indeed build on Mac, I'm looking for alternatives with fewer dependencies.

Comment: That's understandable. I just wanted to leave a response here so people weren't scared of thinking that the Mac wasn't supported at all. But keep in mind that anything you find that has a robust parser and dom will likely be a C extension. Hard to escape dependencies with js because there are no standard libraries.

Comment: Mm. I find JS and Node.js in particular to have extremely disorganized libraries. NPM for the win.

Comment: libxmljs doesn't build on Mac OSX 10.7.3, following those instructions and using NPM. I get <built-in>:0: error: Unknown value ‘140505560121354.140505560121351’ of -mmacosx-version-min