# node.js xml parser on windows

Tags: xml, node.js

I use node.js on windows. I want to evaluate xpath so I'm looking for a node.js xml module that can do this (not sax). So far I found [Libxmljs](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs) but I am not able to install it on windows.

Any idea?

EDIT: I prefer not to use cygwin as more people will work on this and my experience is that cygwin will be confusing.

EDIT: This is [the solution](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2012/03/xml-stack-for-nodejs-that-works-on.html)

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931099/alternatives-to-libxmljs

Comment: thanks but the only relevant module there is https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-o3-xml which also requires cgwin...

Comment: I need to do a lot of xpath queries and dom manipulations, sax is not optimized for that.

Comment: I was about to post an answer mentioning an article in DZone, but then I realised that it was written by _yourself_!
It is fair to post it by yourself and select it as a correct answer :)

Comment: this is the solution http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2012/03/xml-stack-for-nodejs-that-works-on.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it - use [xmldom](https://github.com/jindw/xmldom) with [xpath.js](http://xpath.js/). Full details [are here](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2012/03/xml-stack-for-nodejs-that-works-on.html).

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js

Comment: thanks but there does not seem to be xpath nor namespaces support. I need a full fledged parser.

Comment: @YaronNaveh: For what? I can't imagine anything you can't do in JS.

Comment: I try to implement the "xml encryption" standard. this is so I can interop with existing system. so I don't just care about the data, I really care about the format, namespaces etc. it would not make sense to do xml manipulations on json.